# Reaction of perchloric acid with cyclopropenol

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds

**Question:**

> Identify A and B.
>
> [image]

**My attempt**

The first step will be the attack of $\ce{PhMgX}$ on carbonyl carbon, that is, 1,2 position followed by hydrolysis, yielding an alcohol.

But how does the reaction proceed with $\ce{HClO4}$?

Comment: you should read about cyclopropenyl cation in aromaticity section of advanced organic books.  HClO4 is a strong protonating agent and should protonate OH-group, that will leave. The remaining cation is known to be remarkably stable in organic chemistry and have stable salts.

Comment: @permeakra it is remarkably stable yes, but getting rid of the strained ring by oxidative cleavage (similar to hot $\ce{KMnO4}$) seems way more plausible. We shouldn't ignore the oxidative capabilities of $\ce{HClO4}$

Comment: The answer provided is wrong . Whenever cyclic conjugated ketones comes in question then the conjugation is the unsaturated part is the point of action. Which means double bond will be attacked.

Comment: Can you provide a reference?

Answer (score 7):

The first step is indeed 1,2-addition of the Grignard reagent to the keto group, and product **A** is the alcohol:

[image]

Treatment of the alcohol with the strong acid $\ce{HClO4}$ cannot yield the usual dehydration product (alkene) in this case, as the corresponding alkene would have two double bonds in an already highly strained three-membered ring, which is highly unfavorable. Instead, after protonation of the $\ce{OH}$ group and subsequent loss of $\ce{H2O}$, the carbocation:

[image]

is obtained as the final product **B** (with $\ce{ClO4-}$ being the counteranion). The planar cyclopropenyl cation is a [Hückel aromatic compound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%BCckel%27s_rule) with $(4 \cdot 0+2) = 2$ $\pi$ electrons, and delocalization of the positive charge over the two phenyl substituents can provide further stabilization.

Comment: Carbocation as the final product, really interesting!

Comment: Yes this happens when the intermediate is highly stable with a stable ion like flouro borate, perchlorate etc. (Note that stable counter ion makes the ionic compound to be formed easily according to fajan's rules

Comment: @Archer I think this answer disregards $\ce{HClO4}$'s oxidative abilities. I think the stability gained by cleaving the alkene is far more than the resonance of the carbocation.

Comment: @napstablook $\ce{HClO4}$ is often used in dilute solution where it dissociates, and [then the oxidation power of the perchlorate ion is kinetically squashed](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/117771/17175). Perchloric acid here is acting only as an acid.